# ¿como usar sdkman para gestionar versiones de java?

Tags: java, sdk, control-de-versiones

Tengo instalado sdkman version 5.15.0, con él instale dos versiones de Java, 8.332.08.1-amzn y 11.0.15-ms, utilicé en sdk "sdk use java 8.332.08.1-amzn" y me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si pregunto por la version actual con "sdk current java"\

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si consulto por la version de java con "java --version" me devuelve la version 11
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que estoy haciendo mal?